# execute several times a test with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to run a test x times with py.test?

What I'm looking for it's to repeat a test several times, because the tests has random fixtures.

Something like py.test -n100

I've been playing with pytest-xdist but if I understand well it only distributes the tests among the cpus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you may try running with pytest-xdist like this:

```
py.test --dist=each --tx=3*popen
```

This will run the same tests 3 times in three different subprocesses.